# Elapsed time with multiple End events in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm using Elastic Search to parse the data. Below is my sample log file and I'm using the below Ruby filter to find elapsed time between **Start and End (**which is either Saved or Modified**)** for a given ID

**Sample Log File**

```
       TIMESTAMP            EVENT    ID
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:22.337 Start    1
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:23.215 Saved    1
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:24.440 Start    2
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:24.964 Saved    2
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:25.359 Modified 2
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:29.587 Start    3
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:31.562 Saved    3
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:31.914 Modified 3
Apr 28, 2020 @ 20:07:52.946 Start    4
Apr 28, 2020 @ 20:07:53.304 Saved    4
```

**Ruby Filter**

```
ruby {
        code => "
            if event.get('Event') == 'Start'
                @save_the_timestamp = event.get('@timestamp')
                @save_the_ID = event.get('ID')
            elsif event.get('LOGLEVEL2') == 'Saved' && event.get('ID') == @save_the_ID
                event.set('elapsed_time', event.get('@timestamp') - @save_the_timestamp)
            elsif event.get('LOGLEVEL2') == 'Modified' && event.get('ID') == @save_the_ID
                event.set('elapsed_time', event.get('@timestamp') - @save_the_timestamp)
            end
        "
    }
```

**Current output using Ruby filter**

```
       TIMESTAMP            EVENT       ID   elapsed_time
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:22.337 Start       1       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:23.215 Saved       1     0.878
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:24.440 Start       2       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:24.964 Saved       2     0.524
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:25.359 Modified    2     0.919
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:29.587 Start       3       -       
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:31.562 Saved       3     1.975 
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:31.914 Modified    3     2.327 
Apr 28, 2020 @ 20:07:52.946 Start       4       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 20:07:53.304 Saved       4     0.358
```

But, I would like to have a **single elapsed_time for a given ID**. This helps me for  easy visualization in Kibana. 
Aggregate does this but pushes it as a separate event. Is there any way in the last event of the given ID like  in the below the desired output.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Desired output**

```
       TIMESTAMP            EVENT       ID   elapsed_time
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:22.337 Start       1       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:23.215 Saved       1     0.878
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:24.440 Start       2       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:24.964 Saved       2       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 15:17:25.359 Modified    2     0.919
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:29.587 Start       3       -       
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:31.562 Saved       3       -   
Apr 28, 2020 @ 16:18:31.914 Modified    3     2.327 
Apr 28, 2020 @ 20:07:52.946 Start       4       -
Apr 28, 2020 @ 20:07:53.304 Saved       4     0.358
```

Comment: Each line of your log file is an event or are you using multiline? If each line is an event that you store in elasticsearch after it pass through logstash, to have the `elapsed_time` only in the last event you would need to query elasticsearch and update the document. You can create visualizations in kibana where you get only the last event for a given id.

Comment: Each line in my log file is an event. How would I do that after pushing in to ES? Is there any API for this purpose?

Comment: You can use the [`elasticsearch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) filter in your pipeline to make queries to elasticsearch and get a document.

Answer (score 0):

just randomly stumbled into this question.  Without more context, here is what im thinking. Looking at your conditional statement, you're printing saved or modified events.

Based on your "current output" vs "desired output" and your conditional logic, you could achieve your goal by storing a single "highest value" of saved or modified values per ID.

That is, every time i see a "save" or "modify" rather than just setting the output, add it to a data structure, then run your log output. Below is some poorly written pseudo code.

Depending on how many times you run this logging, a local Redis instance or a cloud solution like Firestore would be great for holding onto that hash.

```
// create an empty hash
// we'll use to store our ID's and timestamps
some_hash => {}

// observe a save or modify and get the id

// see if the id is in the hash
if some_hash.include? unique_id
  //if it does include it, then update the value
  if current_observed_value > some_hash[:unique_id]
    some_hash[:unique_id] = current_observed_value // update the value with higher value
  end
else
  some_hash[:unique_id] = current_observed_value // first time saving the value
end

//you could be a bit more clever and say something like:
if unique_id is NOT in hash or current_observed_value > some_hash[:unique_id]
  some_hash[:unique_id] = current_observed_value
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @chirsallick for your reply. I am using Elastic Search to parse the log files. Not sure if Hash works here. 
I'm a newbie with Ruby and your code looks complicated to me. Could you break it down?

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, well I think you can just update your Ruby filter. I'll take a look later and see if I can get it working.